# Show that $A$ is an invertible matrix if $\left(A+I\right)^3=0$ and find $A^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

> If $A\in M_{n\times n}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ is such that $ (A+I)^3=0$, show that $A$ is an invertible matrix and find the inverse of $A$.

My idea was:
\begin{eqnarray*}
0&=&\left(A+I\right)^3\\
&=&A^3+3A^2I+3AI^2+I^3\\
&=&A^3+3A^2+3A+I,
\end{eqnarray*}
then
$$I=-A^3-3A^2-3A,$$
so
$$I=A\left(-A^2-3A-3I\right).$$
It follows that
$$A^{-1}=-A^2-3A-3I.$$

Now I found the inverse matrix, but how does this show that an inverse actually exists?

Comment: What is $E$? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by a regular matrix? Surely not every matrix is regular...

Comment: With regular, do you mean _invertible_? The _Also $(A+E)^3=0$_ part, is that to be proved or to be assumed?

Comment: Your idea works well. However, if one wanted to check whether $A\;$ is invertible or not without doing the calculations you did you can take a look at the eigenvalues of $A$.
Since $(A+I)\;$ is nilpotent $\; (A+I)\;$only has the eigenvalues $\:\lambda =0$ $$(A+I)v=\lambda v$$ You get $$Av =(\lambda-I)v$$ Hence $\; A \;$is invertible because it has non-zero eigenvalues

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is good, it works. You have shown that
$$A(-A^2-3A-3I)=I,$$
which means that $-A^2-3A-3I=A^{-1}$ by definition of the inverse. This also shows that the inverse exists, because you have constructed it already.

Answer (score 2):

This question is quite unclear. However, if your question is:

*Given $(A+I)^3=0$, show that $A$ is invertible*

Then you are on the right track. Namely, you have shown $A$ is invertible by showing there is a matrix $B$ such that $AB=I$.

Answer (score 1):

You have found out characteristic polynomial of $A$ is which is the expansion of $(A+I)^3$ so by pre  multiplying both the sides with $A^{-1}$ you get a characteristic polynomial for its inverse  . now also you have shown that $A.x=0$ which implies the matrix is invertible. Note $x$ denote whats inside the bracket which is multiplied by A

Answer (score -1):

All of you are right actually but for one minor overlook perhaps... the given relationship between A and I cannot be interpreted as characterstic polynomial but rather MINIMAL POLYNOMIAL because A is of order n rather than three. Keeping that in mind, proving invertibility of A is simple: all eigenvalues of A are non-zero; each being -1, and therefore, det(A)= Product of eigenvalues is non-zero as well and hence, inverse of A exists. As far as, construction of the inverse goes, may be we require more information, just like that in this case A has been assumed to be a 3 x 3 matrix.